# Symfony - use service from another bundle

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I am attempting to use a service from another bundle, without creating any dependencies between the bundles.  I'm trying to use `CompilerPass` but this might not be the best method.

I have created a `ParamConverter` in BarBundle which FooBundle should use for it's Controllers.

However I get the error: `No converter named foo_bundle.converter_service found for conversion of parameter fooObject`

What I have so far:

app/config/config.yml

```
foo_bundle:
    converter_service: bar_bundle.converter.object
```

src/BarBundle/config/service.yml

```
services:
    bar_bundle.converter.object:
        class: BarBundle\ParamConverter\ObjectParamConverter
        tags:
            - { name: request.param_converter, priority: 0, converter: bar_bundle.converter.object }
```

src/FooBundle/DependencyInjection/FooBundleExtension.php

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('services.yml');

    $container->setParameter('foo_bundle.converter_service.id', $config['converter_service']);
}
```

src/FooBundle/FooBundle.php

```
public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    parent::build($container);

    $container->addCompilerPass(new CompilerPass());
}
```

src/FooBundle/DependencyInjection/CompilerPass.php

```
public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $convertserService = $container->getDefinition($container->getParameter('foo_bundle.converter_service.id'));
    $container->setDefinition('foo_bundle.converter_service', $convertserService);
}
```

Controller Annotation:

```
/**
 * Show Feed document.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/add", name="object_add")
 * @ParamConverter("fooObject", converter="foo_bundle.converter_service")
 */
public function addAction(ObjectInterface $fooObject)
```

If I call `$container->get('foo_bundle.converter_service')` in the CompilerPass I can see the object is correctly getting set.

Is it a priority issue? I.e. is the `CompilerPass` run after annotations are parsed.  Or is this just the wrong approach?

Answer (score 1):

As `@ParamConverter` are also load with a `CompilerPass`, you probably have to force yours to be execute first.

Note that default compiler pass priority is 0 and higher the priority, the earlier it's executed.

Try this :

```
public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    parent::build($container);
    $container->addCompilerPass(new CompilerPass(), PassConfig::TYPE_BEFORE_OPTIMIZATION, 30);
}
```

Comment: I can see that should work having read the docs https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html#controlling-the-pass-ordering, but I still get the error `No converter named foo_bundle.converter_service found for conversion of parameter fooObject`.  I think I will try a different approach by splitting the paramConverter into method calls within the action.